# Manage video metadata across Final Cut Libraries?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, production, metadata

We have a massive 15TiB FCPX Library that takes 20 minutes to open and can only be worked on by one person. How can we edit the metadata, such as descriptions of what's in the clips, and have it sync across Libraries?

We've given up and are looking at using a third party tool such the ones below. But we still want to be able to add metadata from a video we see on on the FCPX timeline.

- http://www.keyflowpro.com/
- https://videux.com/
- Text files with metadata

Comment: What meta data you want to edit. There are a lot.

Comment: Descriptions of whats in the clips... such as what they are doing, regulations they are following, weather, company affiliation etc

Comment: If you have such a large library already, putting more stuff into the files seems not a good idea. When you had set that footage is included into the library you might want to change that. With large amount of footage it’s better to not copy it into the library.

Answer (score 0):

If FCPX is reading the meta data only some can be changed as the meta data come from the video file and not from FCPX. So any library you load the video file into should show the same metadata.
If you change the metadata on the files with a 3rd party it should change in any library you use the file.
Playing with metadata from a file can cause problems and even make it unreadable.